# How to dynamically add Html helper controls for same model attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.

My idea is to have modal view like on the picture.

[image: Modal window view as I have imagined it]

When I click on "Add" I would like to add dropdownlist with same items inside like the others before. (Dynamically adding Html helper controls) At the end when I have selected values I would like to put strings together and send then to one string argument in POST method.

So in example if I have Steven in first drop down and Peter chosen in second drop down I would like to send PeterSteven (or Peter,Steven or Peter Steven) in my POST method in controller.

I have tried using partial view for that part of the modal view but the problem is that all my drop down ID's are the same and that is not valid HTML.

I have used this approach for adding drop downs and it worked, just the ID's were the same and I could not get every selected value and put them together and send them to POST method in my controller.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

I am open for new ideas, because I do not like the concept that I am using now.

Comment: Your selects need the same `name` attribute (say) `name="Name"` and then it will bind to a parameter `string[] Name`. But why would you do this rather than a listbox of checkboxlist?

Comment: Because I have 75 files that need to be listed in that drop down and i have to put them together and set Model.Attribute = (all of them together) in POST method. Thank you though, I did not tried setting the name attribute  so far, I tried giving same Id.

Comment: So you happy that instead of the user scrolling through one list and make all the selections in one action, that the user has to scroll through one list, then click a button then scroll through another list etc etc (and be able to pick duplicates)? - terrible UI

Comment: You have a point there. I did not understood right the first time i read it. As I said I am open for new ideas and I think I am going to accept this one.

Comment: This sounds like you want a checkbox list where the checkboxes all have the same name so that you are posting a string[] of the the names.  Although 75 checkboxes sounds like an ugly ui.

Comment: I used select2 editor with MultiSelect enabled so I just click the files I like in dropdown. That way ducplicates are not possible also.